# Android SDK 10 . Please select Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I have a problem to selece last SDK (API level 29).
This is my Project Configuration:

[image]

And this is my Project Structure:

[image]

"File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files" don't work...

Can you help me?
Many thanks!

Comment: What is says? Please share your log details.

Comment: Did you specify the SDK location?

Comment: This is the log after Sync:

16/01/2020
11.44 Gradle sync started with single-variant sync
11.44 Project setup started
11.44 Gradle sync finished in 1 s 102 ms
11.44 NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
11.44 Source generation ended in 349 ms


SDK locatio is correct, it's the same of others SDK. If I select, for example, API Level 28, works fine.

Comment: In the 2nd picture on the left there is "SDK location" can you click on it and verify all is ok there?

Comment: Yes, it's the same path of any SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is my SDK Location, if I select other SDK works fine:

[image]